# How to retrieve specific field of the record just inserted to DB

Tags: sql, asp-classic

i'm using sql server 2008
i insert the data using .Addnew

i have code like this

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table"
rs.CursorType = 2
rs.LockType = 3
rs.Open strSQL, adoCon
rs.AddNew
rs.fields("pid") = pid
rs.fields("name") = name
rs.update
rs.requery
response.write rs.fields("GUID")
rs.close
```

i don't get an error - i get a nothing printed

i do in in classic asp, no stored procedure, nothing special
the guid column is not a key! it has a default value of newid() and the value is there in the db i just can't get it

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `SELECT @@IDENTITY` to the SQL statement to retrieve the last inserted identity:

```
Dim rs , cmd
Set rs = server.createobject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set cmd = server.createobject("ADODB.Command")

cmd.ActiveConnection = GetConnectionString()
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into Table (pid, name) values (1, 'the name') SELECT @@IDENTITY"


rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

response.write "Last GUID: " + rs(0)
```

Comment: that is what i ending up doing but still need to have another select for getting the  guid and not the identity column

Comment: You don't need another select, just do `SELECT GuidColumn FROM Table WHERE idColumn = @@IDENTITY`

Answer (score 0):

This article explains the means of getting identity value with example code. If you need more help after this let us know

http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/how-do-i-get-the-identity/autonumber-value-for-the-row-i-inserted.html